# Writing Recursive File and Directory Function PHP Using Recursive Directory Iterator

Tags: php, recursion, iterator, directory

Having issues writing a function to return the directories contained within one directory and then placing all of each directories file paths into an array called $files.

I've got the Directory collection working, but can't seem to create the file array

Here's the code I have so far:

```
<?php 

  function find_recursive_images_and_dirs($path, $option) {
      try {
        $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path),
                                                RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
        foreach ($iterator as $path) {
          if ($path->isDir()) {
            if(substr($path->__toString(), (strrpos($path->__toString(), "/")+1)) != "." && substr($path->__toString(), (strrpos($path->__toString(), "/")+1)) != ".."){
              $directories[] = $path->__toString();
              $childrenIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(($path->__toString() . "/")), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
              //echo $path->getChildren() . "</br>";
              echo "<pre>" . var_dump($path) . "</pre>";
              foreach ($childrenIterator as $child) {
                echo "Entered!2";
                if(substr($path->__toString(), (strrpos($path->__toString(), "/")+1)) != "." && substr($path->__toString(), (strrpos($path->__toString(), "/")+1)) != ".."){
                  echo "Entered!3";
                  echo $child->__toString();
                  $files[] = $child->__toString();
                }
              }
            }
          } /*else {
             $files[] = $path->__toString();
          }*/
        }
        if($option == "files")
          return $files;
        else if($option == "directories")
          return $directories;
      } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "/* There was a problem, error: " . $e . " */";
      }

  }

  $path = "../administrator/panel/gallery/public/";
  $files = find_recursive_images_and_dirs($path, "files");
  $directories = find_recursive_images_and_dirs($path, "directories");
  print_r($files);
?>
```

I tried the getChildren() method, but it just spits out an error, so I ended up trying to create a new recursive directory iterator using the dir path returned when checking whether the file is a directory in the main folder. The program then uses that path and does the same thing, only this time it places the files listed in each folder in an array named $files, but for some reason, nothing is being stored in the array, in fact, it doesn't even enter the second foreach().

Comment: I don't know if you're maybe reinventing the wheel for academic purposes, but you might want to have a look at libraries like Symfony's Filesystem component: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html

Comment: No I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel. This is the thing that I seen first and I managed to get it working, didn't know there were other Classes I could use. Cheers.

Comment: Actually, I'd rather use stuff that was built into PHP, don't really want to include external source and make for more hassle during set up.

Comment: I understand your concerns, but these libraries are well tested and supported by a huge community, with a long-term commitment to maintenance. In the end, using a proven framework for basic functionality will instantly increase your code quality. And it will make coding fun, because you can concentrate on the business logic, instead of fiddeling with low-level problems that have already been solved dozens of times.

Comment: I understand this, but this is literally all i need for file manipulation. So it'd be a bit pointless including a massive library when i'm already halfway there using in built PHP stuff. Not trying to be annoying, just saying.